# Como puedo extraer varios valores de un arreglo?

Tags: java

> Estoy intentando encontrar una forma de poder extraer los valores de un arreglo en dos formas distintas, la primera es diciendo cuantos valores son mayores a X numero.
>
> La otra es indicando cuales son los valores que son menores a X numero.
>
> En este caso X numero es un promedio, el cual es un valor que ya he podido conseguir y puedo decir cuales valores pertenecen al numero mas alto y mas bajo al igual que mostrar el promedio de todos los numeros del arreglo, sin embargo, estoy intentando conseguir lo que describi anteriormente. De momento todo lo que tengo funciona sin problema, pero necesito cambiar lo que anote abajo.

> Este es un arreglo con 10 numeros.
> Gracias por la ayuda.

```
//Cantidad de valores mayores al promedio - CAMBIAR
   public int getMayoresPromedio(){
int mayores;
for (int indice=1;indice<conjunto.length;indice++){
   if(mayores>conjunto[indice]);}
return mayores;}

//Mostrar valores menores al promedio - CAMBIAR
   public int getMenoresPromedio(){
int menores;
menores=conjunto[0];

for (int indice=1;indice>conjunto.length;indice++){
if(menores>=conjunto[indice])
   menores=conjunto[indice];}
 return menores;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para devolver varios valores tu método tendría que devolver el conjunto de números mayores o menores al promedio y no un solo valor, suponiendo que devuelvas un array con los valores mayores al promedio primero tendrías que obtener la cantidad de esos números para poder declarar el array

```
    public static int[]getMayoresPromedio(int[]conjunto,int promedio){
    
    int cont=0;
    //usando una variable que aumente en 1 cada vez que se encuentre un numero mayor al promedio podes obtener el tamaño del array que almacenara dichos numeros
    for (int i=0;i<conjunto.length;i++){
       if(conjunto[i]>promedio){
         cont++;
       }
    }
    //declaras el array con la cantidad obtenida
    int []mayoresDelPromedio=new int[cont];
    int j=0;
//nuevamente aplicas el mismo for solo que esta vez lo guardas en el array que te //mostrara los valores mayores al promedio
    for (int i=0;i<conjunto.length;i++){
       if(conjunto[i]>promedio){
         mayoresDelPromedio[j]=conjunto[i];
         j++;
       }
    }
    return mayoresDelPromedio;
    
    }
```

para los menores seria duplicar el código solo habría que cambiar el símbolo `>` por `<`

Pero existe una opción mas corta y es a partir de java+8 , usando el método [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) el cual al recibir una condicional filtrara los valores del array en base a la condicional aplicada

Ejemplo:

```
int [] numeros={1,3,7,9,8,5,12,6,4};

int promedio=(int)Arrays.stream(numeros).average().orElse(0);//6

int[]mayoresDelPromedio=Arrays.stream(numeros).filter(p-> p>promedio).toArray();
int[]menoresDelPromedio=Arrays.stream(numeros).filter(p-> p<promedio).toArray();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]